# Quick sort recursive function in C - doesn't work with big number of elements

Tags: c, function, recursion, quicksort

Has this function been written correctly?

It seems that something is wrong when I try to run the function with a large number of elements in the array (eg 1000).

Then its appears to stop.

```
int quick_sort(int n, int tablica[],int b, int a)
    {   
        if(a==n-1 || n==0) return;
        if(b==n-1) 
        {
            b=0;
            a++;        
        }

        if(tablica[b]>tablica[b+1])
        {
            bufor=tablica[b];
            tablica[b]=tablica[b+1];
            tablica[b+1]=bufor;
        }
        b++;
        return quick_sort(n,tablica,b,a);
    }
```

Comment: Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show it to us. Lastly I recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This does not even remotely look like a quicksort

Comment: Did you at least check that none of your array index ever get out of bounds? The C language won't do it for you. Also show a [mcve] please

Comment: Looks like this will recurse at least once for each element. That will use a lot of stack space.

Comment: It looks like this should be some kind of bubblesort, which would recurse n² times in this implementation (n being the number of elements). Quite a deep recursion, which not every system will handle out of the box.

Comment: Is it some kinda modified quicksort? Why don't I see two recursive calls with a partition logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code will not work even for a small array, unless the small array is unsorted in a particular way. It compares one element with the next element. If the array is say `{4,3,8,7,1}` the sort will fail, because it has no mechanism to push `1` to the start of the array.

For larger arrays there are too many recursion and the program hits the stack limit and simply fails.

You can use recursion in quicksort but the number of recursions has to be kept in check. For example for array of size 1000 you don't want to have to more than 1000 recursion. Example:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int pivot = arr[high];    
        int i = (low - 1);  
        for(int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;    
                swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            }
        }
        swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
        int pi = i + 1;

        quicksort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quicksort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 7,3,6,1,4,8,9,2 };
    int arrsize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    quicksort(arr, 0, arrsize - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```